# Float.isNaN 'receiver type mismatch' error in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, types, casting, double, nan

I am  new to Kotlin and having an issue with Kotli'ns built-in FLoat.isNaN and Double.isNaN functions. When using the Float.isNaN function to test for NaN equalt of a float arraylist I receive the error:

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
>
> - public inline fun Double.isNaN(): Boolean defined in kotlin public
> - inline fun Float.isNaN(): Boolean defined in kotlin

Pseudocode is listed below, appreciate any help:

```
var scores = arrayListOf<Float>()
val todaysResult = scores[0]
if(Float.isNaN(todaysResult)) {
    todayResultNumericTextView!!.text = "-"
} else {
    todayResultNumericTextView!!.text = Math.round(todaysResult).toString() + "%"
}
```

Comment: You need to do `todaysResult.isNan()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`isNaN`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/is-na-n.html) is an extension function on `Float` and `Double` (not a "static" method, unlike in Java!) This means you must invoke it with the value as the receiver.

```
fun Double.isNaN(): Boolean
fun Float.isNaN(): Boolean
```

---

Instead of

```
Float.isNaN(todaysResult)
```

you want

```
todaysResult.isNaN()
```

---

This is also indicated by the error message:

> `public inline fun Double.isNaN(): Boolean` defined in `kotlin`
> `public inline fun Float.isNaN(): Boolean` defined in `kotlin`

The syntax `Float.isNaN()` indicates that this function takes a *receiver* of type `Float`.

---

See also: [Extensions (Kotlin reference)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)